# How to obtain the total page count for a pdf in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, footer, page-numbering

I've created a class that extends PdfPageEventHelper to add a specific message at the end of the page. The problem is that this text need to be added only to the end of the PDF (if I have 3 pages this text need to be displayed only on the footer of the last page).

In the OnEndPage function of the PdfPageEventHelper class I use document.PageNumber to know what page I'm modifying, but how can I know if this page is the last one?

Thanks.

Comment: Can I use OnClodeDocument for this?

Answer (score 2):

(**writer**.PageNumber - 1) is the last page.

Comment: This answer is correct. it should be called from the PdfPageEventHelper class.